# How to sed a string that has quotes and backslashes?

Tags: bash, sed

Im having trouble trying to use 'sed' to replace a strings in a file that has quotes and backslashes.

I tried this and many other tries without success:

```
sed -e 's/"\u001b[0;31mUnkwn\u001b[0m"/"UNKWOWN"/g' file.txt
```

Input:

```
"Vendor": "\u001b[0;31mUnknown\u001b[0m"
```

Desired output:

```
"Vendor": "Unknown"
```

Comment: Is fixing whatever is generating that input file to not output those escape sequences in the first place an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the color patterns are like the ones you describe in your question, this may be a solution:

```bsh
$ foo='"Vendor": "\u001b[0;31mUnknown\u001b[0m"'
$ echo "$foo"  | sed 's/\\u[0-9a-z]*\[[;0-9]*m\(.*\)\\u[0-9a-z]*\[[;0-9]*m/\U\1/'
"Vendor": "UNKNOWN"
```

Comment: I like this second solution because it get rids of all strange code color patterns without worrying of any word between them. But both anwers are very useful. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: @JavierGonzalez Thanks, be aware that this is not tested against every possible color pattern...

Answer (score 2):

You can chain 2 sed commands like that:

```
sed 's,\\u001b\[0\;31m,,' | sed 's,\\u001b\[0m,,'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '"Vendor": "\u001b[0;31mUnknown\u001b[0m"' | sed 's,\\u001b\[0\;31m,,' | sed 's,\\u001b\[0m,,'
"Vendor": "Unknown"
```